# The name "RichTextBox" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, toolkit, xceed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extended WPF Toolkit - using the RichTextBoxFormatBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188373/extended-wpf-toolkit-using-the-richtextboxformatbar)

This has been driving me mad. I've used the WPF Extended Toolkit before but trying it now, even on a completely new project (see screenshot), doesn't work. I get the errors pictured.

I can't embed images as I'm a new user to stackoverflow (but long time lurker).

A screenshot that captures whole problem is here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRwl8.png

Basically if I create a brand new project, add the reference to the WPFExtended toolkit .dll (unmodified in any way) and then add the namespace to the mainwindow.xaml and then try to add a  (or any other control I've tested so far), I get:

"The name "RichTextBox" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit""

What the heck? I've used this before a few times, why am I getting such aggro now?

Is this an issue with Visual Studio (Express) 2012 / .net 4.5?

Update:
I seem to be able to create the object fine in the code behind and in spite of the errors with xaml the application still "builds"... weirdly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10193020/1217408 ?

Comment: Thank you TheZ! That was it! I had neglected to "unblock" the .dll.