# WPFToolkit : Type reference cannot find a public type

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wpftoolkit

Since moving on to a new PC I've been having trouble getting a project to run on it, specifically the problem is with some of the controls from the WPFToolkit.

On my previous set up I'd downloaded WPFToolkit and unblocked the DLL's and they'd worked (after [some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188373/extended-wpf-toolkit-using-the-richtextboxformatbar)). However, this time I downloaded them via NuGet and they *aren't* blocked where they are stored in the packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.1.9.0/lib directory.

However, I'm now getting errors like :

```
The name "AutoCompleteBox" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit".
```

or

```
The type reference cannot find a public type named 'AutoCompleteBox'.
```

I'm referencing the files in the XAML with :

```
xmlns:controls="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

From all the research I've done on this problem that seems the right way to do it and it worked when I was on my previous machine.

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you changed .NET Framework version *after* adding the Nuget package? I have noticed that occasionally Nuget does not update the referenced libraries after a framework change which could cause the kind of error you are experiencing. In that case, try to manually remove and re-add the Nuget libraries to your project.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson - Thanks for the suggestion. The project has stayed the same version, I wasn't sure if the wpfToolkit had changed from the version I'd originally used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AutoCompleteBox` is a component of the "original" [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) which is also available on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/wpftoolkit) under the simple name *WPF Toolkit*.

The [Extended WPF Toolkit Community Edition](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) is a completely different control library developed by Xceed. The controls from the original *WPF Toolkit* are **not** included in the *Extended WPF Toolkit*.

In your project, simply remove the NuGet reference to the *Extended WPF Toolkit* and instead add a reference to *WPF Toolkit*.

To access the `AutoCompleteBox` in your XAML file, add the following namespace reference:

```
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
```